# C# - RSACryptoServiceProvider Decrypt into a SecureString instead of byte array

Tags: c#, encryption, arrays, rsa, securestring

I have a method that currently returns a string converted from a byte array:

```
public static readonly UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
public static string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt, string privateKeyXml)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToDecrypt))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Cannot decrypt null or blank string"
        );
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(privateKeyXml))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid private key XML given");
    }
    byte[] bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
    byte[] decryptedBytes;
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);
        decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(bytesToDecrypt, FOAEP);
    }
    return ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedBytes);
}
```

I'm trying to update this method to instead return a `SecureString`, but I'm having trouble converting the return value of `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt` from `byte[]` to `SecureString`.  I tried the following:

```
var secStr = new SecureString();
foreach (byte b in decryptedBytes)
{
    char[] chars = ByteConverter.GetChars(new[] { b });
    if (chars.Length != 1)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "Could not convert a single byte into a single char"
        );
    }
    secStr.AppendChar(chars[0]);
}
return secStr;
```

However, using [this SecureString equality tester](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/555a5cb6-790d-415d-b079-00d62b3a9632/), the resulting `SecureString` was not equal to the `SecureString` constructed from the original, unencrypted text.  My Encrypt and Decrypt methods worked before, when I was just using `string` everywhere, and I've also tested the `SecureString` equality code, so I'm pretty sure the problem here is how I'm trying to convert `byte[]` into `SecureString`.  Is there another route I should take for using RSA encryption that would allow me to get back a `SecureString` when I decrypt?

**Edit:** I didn't want to convert the byte array to a regular string and then stuff that string into a `SecureString`, because that seems to defeat [the point of using a `SecureString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141203/when-would-i-need-a-securestring-in-net) in the first place.  However, is it also bad that `Decrypt` returns `byte[]` and I'm then trying to stuff that byte array into a `SecureString`?  It's my guess that if `Decrypt` returns a `byte[]`, then that's a safe way to pass around sensitive information, so converting one secure representation of the data to another secure representation seems okay.

Comment: You might find this article helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SymmetricAlgorithmHelper.aspx?PageFlow=Fluid It does decrypt the data to a byte array and converts it to a SecureString.  Only other slight improvement I could think of is to put your Decrypted output in a foreach loop and not store it in a byte array.

Comment: Hm, that link has code that explicitly stores data in an array so that they can flush the array later:  `Array.Clear(utf8Buffer, 0, utf8Buffer.Length);`.  Can someone chime in on which is better?  Maybe I should post another question.  :/

Comment: The strings should be the same. How are you encrypting? Using the same value for the FOAEP value? Can you give an example of the string that isn't decrypting correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Coding Gorilla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503543/c-rsacryptoserviceprovider-decrypt-into-a-securestring-instead-of-byte-array/4503620#4503620), I tried the following in my `Decrypt` method:

```
string decryptedString1 = string.Empty;
foreach (byte b in decryptedBytes)
{
    decryptedString1 += (char)b;
}
string decryptedString2 = ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedBytes);
```

When debugging, `decryptedString1` and `decryptedString2` were not equal:

```
decryptedString1    "m\0y\0V\0e\0r\0y\0L\0o\0n\0g\0V\03\0r\0y\05\03\0c\0r\03\07\0p\04\0s\0s\0w\00\0r\0d\0!\0!\0!\0"
decryptedString2    "myVeryLongV3ry53cr37p4ssw0rd!!!"
```

So it looks like I can just go through the `byte[]` array, do a direct cast to `char`, and skip `\0` characters.  Like Coding Gorilla said, though, this does seem to again in part defeat the point of `SecureString`, because the sensitive data is floating about in memory in little `byte`-size chunks.  Any suggestions for getting `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt` to return a `SecureString` directly?

**Edit:** yep, this works:

```
var secStr = new SecureString();
foreach (byte b in decryptedBytes)
{
    var c = (char)b;
    if ('\0' == c)
    {
        continue;
    }
    secStr.AppendChar(c);
}
return secStr;
```

**Edit:** correction: this works with plain old English strings.  Encrypting and then attempting to decrypt the string `"標準語 明治維新 english やった"` doesn't work as expected because the resulting decrypted string, using this `foreach (byte b in decryptedBytes)` technique, does not match the original unencrypted string.

**Edit:** using the following works for both:

```
var secStr = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in ByteConverter.GetChars(decryptedBytes))
{
    secStr.AppendChar(c);
}
return secStr;
```

This still leaves a byte array and a char array of the password in memory, which sucks.  Maybe I should find another RSA class that returns a `SecureString`.  :/

Comment: If you come up with a way to skip the 'insecure' intermediate step, I'd love to hear it. =)

Comment: BTW, if, before encrypting your string, you use the ASCIIEncoder on the string, it will get rid of your `\0`'s.  Those are an artifact of Unicode and MBCS (that is of course assuming you don't need Unicode/MBCS support).

Comment: Write a new `RSACryptoServiceProvider`-type class whose `Decrypt` and `Encrypt` return/use `SecureString` instead of byte arrays?  :P

Comment: I know that I am late to the party on this one, but after you append the character to the string you can set it's value to \0.  Since you are actually dealing with a array of bytes this will wipe out the string as you consume it.  I don't think that there is a way to get around having the byte array of plain text, but you can minimize the amount of time it actually exists.

Answer (score 3):

A char and a byte can be used interchangeably with casting, so modify your second chunk of code as such:

```
var secStr = new SecureString();
foreach (byte b in decryptedBytes)
{
   secStr.AppendChar((char)b);
}

return secStr;
```

This should work properly, but keep in mind that you're still bringing the unencrypted information into the "clear" in memory, so there's a point at which it could be compromised (which sort of defeats the purpose to a `SecureString`).

** **Update** **

A `byte[]` of your sensitive information is not secure.  You can look at it in memory and see the information (especially if it's just a string).  The individual bytes will be in the exact order of the string, so 'read'ing it is pretty straight-forward.

I was (actually about an hour ago) just struggling with this same issue myself, and as far as I know there is no good way to go straight from the decrypter to the `SecureString` unless the decryter is specifically programmed to support this strategy.

Comment: I tried this initially, before using the `ByteConverter`.  My `SecureString`s still weren't equal.  You just prompted me to test something else, though, so let me post a new answer--I think I'm on to something!

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to force the `byte[]` to be wiped from memory after its contents have been read into a `SecureString`?

Comment: Sure you could easily just do a `for(int i=0; i < decryptedBytes.Length; i++) { decryptedBytes[i] = 0; }`.  But all I have to do (as ye ole' hacker) is break the code before you wipe it, and I've got you.

Comment: SwDevMan81 linked this in a comment above:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SymmetricAlgorithmHelper.aspx?PageFlow=Fluid  It stores data in arrays specifically so it can flush them later with `Array.Clear(utf8Buffer, 0, utf8Buffer.Length);`.  Is that effective, I wonder?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem might be your `ByteConvert.GetChars` method. I can't find that class or method in the MSDN docs. I'm not sure if that is a typo, or a homegrown function. Regardless, it is mostly likely not interpreting the encoding of the bytes correctly. Instead, use the [UTF8Encoding's GetChars method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khac988h.aspx). It will properly convert the bytes back into a .NET string, assuming they were encrypted from a .NET string object originally. (If not, you'll want to use the `GetChars` method on the [encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding.aspx) that matches the original string.)

You're right that using arrays is the most secure approach. Because the decrypted representations of your secret are stored in byte or char arrays, you can easily clear them out when done, so your plaintext secret isn't left in memory. This isn't perfectly secure, but more secure than converting to a string. Strings can't be changed and they stay in memory until they are garbage collected at some indeterminate future time.

```
var secStr = new SecureString();
var chars = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(decryptedBytes);
for( int idx = 0; idx < chars.Length; ++idx )
{
    secStr.AppendChar(chars[idx]);
    # Clear out the chars as you go.
    chars[idx] = 0
}

# Clear the decrypted bytes from memory, too.
Array.Clear(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);

return secStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you stuck to UTF-16?

Internally, .NET (and therefore, SecureString) uses UTF-16 (double byte) to store string contents. You could take advantage of this and translate your protected data two bytes (i.e. 1 char) at a time...

When you encrypt, peel off a Char, and use Encoding.UTF16.GetBytes() to get your two bytes, and push those two bytes into your encryption stream. In reverse, when you are reading from your encrypted stream, read two bytes at a time, and UTF16.GetString() to get your char.

It probably sounds awful, but it keeps all the characters of your secret string from being all in one place, AND it gives you the reliability of character "size" (you won't have to guess if the next single byte is a char, or a UTF marker for a double-wide char). There's no way for an observer to know which characters go with which, nor in which order, so guessing the secret should be near impossible.

Honestly, this is just a suggested idea... I'm about to try it myself, and see how viable it is. My goal is to produce extension methods (SecureString.Encrypt and ICrypto.ToSecureString, or something like that).

Answer (score -1):

Use System.Encoding.Default.GetString
[GetString MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx)

Comment: I was trying to avoid having the decrypted text in a regular string, otherwise what's the point of using `SecureString` elsewhere if the sensitive data is already floating around memory in a regular string?  At least from my understanding of things.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141203/when-would-i-need-a-securestring-in-net

Comment: I see, I saw that your method was Decrypt so I assumed you wanted the decrypted value, you could return it as a Base64 using Convert.ToBase64String(thebytes); then maybe use that to pass into your SecureString?