# how start process with admin rights in hide mode

Tags: c#

I am making program that should start a process with admin right and it should be hidden
I tried this but its not working

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\launcher.exe");
           startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

           startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;  
           Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: What for? "admin rights" and "hidden" sets off some alarm bells.

Comment: Besides, it'll be difficult to circumvent UAC. Not that you should.

Answer (score 1):

```
SecureString pass = new SecureString ();
foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray())
{
    pass.AppendChar(c);
}    
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\cmd.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.Domain = "yourdomain"
startInfo.UserName = "yourusername"
startInfo.Password = pass;
Process.Start(Info);
```

Just fill in as needed.

To elevate you must prompt for UAC, to do this you can either use

```
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

or create a manifest file, right click on your project -> Add Item -> Manifest File

Find the line that says

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
```

and change this to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply
but I receive this error

The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: In that case you will need to create a manifest file to prompt for UAC to elevate. I will edit my answer.

Comment: now it doesn't confirm for administrator permissions anymore
but it still not hidden when I start the process it shows for the user
I want it hidden

Comment: the problem not with UAC or with require admin account the problem with hide the program from the screen and run it in background its working with all programs except launcher.exe I dont know why I though that it because it require admin rights

Comment: @AlaaMasalmah that is another question (hide windows), write  another. Main question is about admin rights

Comment: Solution is inaccurate. You cannot combine runas with username and password. To use Verb="runas" you must set UseShellExecute to true and to use user name and password you must set UseShellExecute to false.

Answer (score 0):

hide the window?
then you should try this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

private const int c_SwHide = 0;
private const int c_SwShow = 5;
```

by using the method:

```
static void Main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), c_SwHide);
}
```

hope this helps. :)
If you want to show it again, just replace the second parameter "c_SwHide" with "c_SwShow".

Comment: `return new WindowsPrincipal( WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() ).IsInRole( WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator );` - this should return true when u've got admin privileges. otherwise it'll return false.