# Calling Sav32Cli.exe from asp.net c# application "Code 2 - If some error preventing further execution is discover "

Tags: c#, asp.net, antivirus, antivirus-integration

I have integrated Sav32Cli.exe in my asp.net c# application & its working fine in my local machine but when we move it on the testing server I am getting the following error "Code 2 - If some error preventing further execution is discover "

The scenario is If only 1 person performs the activity it works fine but concurrent connection performs the same activity then I am getting this error for some connections.

Actual scenario : We have the page where users upload the pdf file & as soon as the file is uploaded on the server we perform the scanning via sop-hos and when multiple users perform the same activity I am getting the following error : Code 2 - If some error preventing further execution is discover. So I would like to know from you guys what should I do to bypass this error & implement the scanning successfully into my application.

Below is the code I have written to integrate the scanning into my application :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
try
{
    string filePath = sFileDetails.DirectoryName + "\\" + sFileName;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Sophos\\Sophos Anti-Virus\\sav32cli.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@" -ss ""{0}""", filePath); 
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    StringBuilder objStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    objStrBuilder.AppendLine("Status  " + output.ToString());
    int i = process.ExitCode;
    objStrBuilder.AppendLine("Code " + i.ToString());
    File.WriteAllText(sFileDetails.DirectoryName + "\\" + Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid()) + ".txt", Convert.ToString(objStrBuilder));
    if (i > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
finally
{
    process.Close();
    process.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: you should contact sophos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sav32Cli.exe** requires more permission to execute in web app. So impersonation technique helped me to solve this issue.

This link helped me to solve this issue : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391432/process-on-asp-net-server-not-running-correctly-over-iis)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using SAVIDI for this - https://www.sophos.com/medialibrary/PDFs/partners/sophossavdidsna.ashx

SAV32CLI will take long time to load all the virus data into memory, I would expect around 5 seconds.  This is fine when you're scanning your hard disk but per file it would be rather slow. If you're launching multiple instances then it would be quite a memory drain also.

If your throughput needs improving, I would suggest looking at SAVIDI.  In this scenario there is service which loads the virus data once at startup and you can then ask it to scan a file/directory.

This post and attachment in the thread could help you:
https://community.sophos.com/products/endpoint-security-control/f/sophos-endpoint-software/9420/sophos-sav-di-icap-code-sample

Regards.