# Open and closing from different project under same solution for c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 projects here under the same solution for C#.net
Let's called it project1 and project2. I have project1 been open. 
When I click on a button on project1, it will go then to project2.

```
//using this code
var project2= new project2();
project2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

But I still did not manage to do it. Can anybody suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string exePath = @"C:\Project2\bin\Debug\Project2.exe";// Your exe path
Process.Start(exePath);
this.Hide();
```

I check your version too and it also works

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Project2.Form1 f = new Project2.Form1();
     f.Show();
     this.Hide();
 };
```

Comment: even though I manage to get it run, but the system is running under my username as Im putting my system at C:\....Users\ComputerName\ is there a way for me to change the way the code read my system as if I want to share it with my friends? Thank you

Comment: `http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/startprocessasuser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/start-a-net-process-as-a-different-user`  i hop that this halps you

Comment: Thank you for the info, it does help. Awesome share.