# Batch-file for running commands in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping, ipconfig

I'm working on a little fun school project.

I want to create a windows form application, which runs commands in cmd by opening batch-file. I do not have much experience in using batch-files.

I need help with the following:

1. Batch file which opens cmd
2. Runs a command ONCE only, such as ipconfig, ping, tracert etc.
3. Keeps cmd open with the information

Otherwise good guides for working and learning batch-files are much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remember we are not a free coding service ;)

Comment: To get helped, you shoud prove some effort from you. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43249355/edit) and add what did you tried until now as code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some hints:

1. Batch files open with cmd by default
2. Commands will only run once by default
3. To keep the window open after running the command, use the `/k` switch i.e. `cmd /k ipconfig`

EDIT:

Make this the contents of your batch file:

```
@echo off
ipconfig
```

Then call the batch file like this (from command line/run etc):

```
cmd /k iptest.bat
```

Or from Winform (C#):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k iptest.bat"
p.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you sir! So far i have found out how to create functions and create a console program by using a batch file. But i still have problems. The problem is that i can make my batch-file enter the command in cmd but it does not execute it.

Comment: Right now i got it like:
@echo off
cmd /k ipconfig
pause
This seems to just write ipconfig infinite time on the name of the cmd window.
I tried cmd /k ipconfig with no pause after, this leaves me with an cmd with nothing in it.
Is a better solution to cd to system32 and run the ipconfig.exe?

Comment: You need to call your batch file with `cmd /k`, rather than in the file itself. So in your batch just use `ipconfig`, but from your winform call the process `cmd /k yourbatch.bat`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that i'm using win10 and testing in a virtual enviroment, to avoid having to restart my pc(learn by doing) :D.

Comment: That's fine, should work just the same, best way of learning! :)

Comment: The windows forms is not made yet i want the batch-file to work first.
I tried just to run the batch-file containing ipconfig from cmd, this is what i get: https://i.imgur.com/2aFRjfE.png

The command still does not execute it is only written into cmd and displayed.

Comment: I've updated my answer, just try running the batch from the run prompt rather than a cmd window first to see if it works?

Comment: Seems like the problem was, that i was not running the batch file as admin haha. Thanks for your help, now i need to figure out how to run the batch-file as admin.

Comment: Ah right, I wouldn't have guessed that. That should be quite easy if you are doing through the winform, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/start-a-net-process-as-a-different-user

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work for 2 days now on/off, so i feel pretty stupid. But thanks for the link, you have been a great help!

Comment: Don't worry, I've spent longer on things :) No worries, good luck!