# C# Run Thread as Different Identity

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, identity, impersonation

Is it possible to Run Thread with identity of Local System Account ?

I have a dll , that uses Process.Start to run some tool that has UI , I'd like to hide UI from user , I thought if it possible tu run Thread / Task as Local System , the UI will not be shown.

But I can't find anything helpful on Google , maybe someone can help.

PSEUDOCODE:

```
Task.Run(()=>{
     // Somehow need to tell use Local System to execute this part of code
     MyDll.RunProcess();
     // Hopefully if possible to tell it run as local system , the ui of //MyDLL.RunProcess will be hidden.
  });
```

Comment: Welcome.  You question is too broad.  Any code to show? [ask].  Good luck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/start-a-net-process-as-a-different-user

Comment: Process.Start starts a new process, not a new thread. Running a process as LocalSystem will not cause the UI to be hidden. Your basic assumptions are completely flawed I'm afraid.

Comment: Can I somehow know the password of Local System User ?

Comment: @AhmedMagamedi You want to know how to hide the UI of an application so ask that question, not a completely unrelated question. Note that you will need to include in your question what application you are trying to hide as the mechanism will be specific to that application.