# Getting the output of .exe program in IIS under windows server 2012

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

We have our own C++ compiled OCR as .exe file that takes the image location as a parameter and return a string, and we place it in folder within our web-API 2 application folder, now we start the OCR as a process from the web-api, get the output and return it back.
everything works good in a local machine, when we deploy the API in the server, the output cannot be retrieved unless we replace the Application pool identity with the Admin in the application pool. At this stage we need to use the Application pool identity (or any other user but the admin) and still be able to retrieve the output from the process here is our code:

```
       ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WorkingDirectory = enginepath,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = enginepath+"//"+"OCR.exe",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                Arguments = " "+imageFilepath
            };


        using (Process process = Process.Start(info))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

                return result;
            }
        }
```

we tried all the popular ways from giving the right permissions,loading the user profile=true, and still can't be able to retrieve the output.
*we need to be able to get the output within the web server application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start a .Net Process as a Different User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/start-a-net-process-as-a-different-user)

Comment: @mjwills I asked about starting the process from a web server.

Comment: Yep - hence why I provided that link. Did you try using https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624413/34092 with your admin username and password?

Comment: @mjwills we'll try it rn thank you for the help ;)

Comment: shouldn't you wait for the process to exit before trying to read its output?

Comment: @mjwills unfortunately still the same problem.

Comment: @Stefan the process works when running under Admin as the pool user.

Comment: That simply means your OCR executable requires admin permissions to run. Then your only option is run the pool as admin.