# How to restrict only certain settings in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, uac

I am attempting to write a program in VB.Net to give to certain staff in my organization. It will let them manage some aspects of AD, but only what they have been delegated access for. This part works.

The part that seems to be puzzling me is how to lock down settings in the program to only be allowed by a certain group (i.e. Domain Admins), but not just Local Administrators (i.e. by using UAC). The settings are currently stored in `My.Settings.*`, and are User-scoped settings (so they could be changed at a later date).

Ideally, I'd like a UAC-style dialog to appear, but to authenticate against an Active Directory group, instead of the local system's Administrators group, then the user can change settings. The program will not always be run by a Domain Administrator, but the option to change settings needs to be there if credentials are entered. Is this possible?

Comment: Are users logged running your program under their AD credentials?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes. It is expected the program will error out during the startup routine if it does not have AD credentials to monitor who is doing what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to get the groups for the currently logged on user. There are several different methods, but this is probably the easiest:

```
UserPrincipal.Current.GetAuthorizationGroups()
```

That will get all the security groups that the user is a member of, recursively - so if the user is a member of group A, and that group is in group B, you will see group B in this list. (I actually wrote an article where I discussed how that method works: [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html))

Then you just check that the group you want is there by looking at the `Name` property of the groups in the list.

If you find that's too slow, there is a much faster but not-as-friendly way to do it. The user's authentication token contains all the SIDs of their groups (that's actually what `GetAuthorizationGroups()` uses), but it *only* contains the SIDs. So `GetAuthorizationGroups()` will go out to AD and get the properties of each one (one network request per group).

To avoid that network traffic (and time), you can look at the SIDs directly using this:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
```

That returns a list of [`SecurityIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier). If you store the SID of the group you're using, instead of the name, then you can compare it to the `Value` of the `SecurityIdentifier` and you can do this whole thing without contacting AD at all.

*Update:* All that will help you determine if the user is in the group you want (Domain Admins?). If you want to give the user the option of putting in different credentials, well... there are several ways you could go about that.

The simplest I think is to create your own dialog that takes the username and password, and use the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624413/1202807) to restart your application with the new credentials (translated to VB.NET):

```
Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()

proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath
proc.StartInfo.Domain = "domainname"
proc.StartInfo.UserName = "username"

'Translate the user-entered String into a SecureString
'If you take the password as a SecureString in the first place
'you won't have to do this
Dim password As String = "user entered password"
Dim ssPwd As System.Security.SecureString = New System.Security.SecureString()
For x As Integer = 0 To password.Length - 1
    ssPwd.AppendChar(password(x))
Next
proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd

proc.Start()
Application.Exit()
```

Note that the [documentation on the `UserName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username) says:

> If you use the UPN format, `user`@`DNS_domain_name`, the Domain property must be `null`.

So you may have to check if the user gave you `DOMAIN\Username` or `Username@domain.com` and assign the `UserName` and `Domain` properties appropriately.

Comment: This is great, if the user is also a Domain Admin. My requirement is to have the user run with their normal account, but only the Domain Admin can set the settings through the app. If the current user running the program is not a Domain Admin, I expect an authentication dialog to appear, then to allow the settings to be changed. Does that make sense?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more details that should help you get started.

Comment: Just be aware that `proc.Start()` will throw an exception if they get their credentials wrong.