# How to setup process task in SSIS to execute a bat file located on a server under a different user

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to execute a batch file in SSIS.  This batch file is located on a server on the network.  I need to also pass in different user and password.

I've tried to setup the executable to be the following \networkservername\location and I've tried the cmd.exe and put the runas command on the argument.  Neither worked and I'm not finding clear instructions on how to accomplish this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error that I'm receiving so I don't think it is setup accurately
[image]

Comment: Why do you need to run in it under a different user account?

Comment: Because the bat jobs does inserts into production sql tables.  I can run the bat job when I'm logged in the server with no problem.

Comment: How're you executing the ssis packages? SQL agent job?

Comment: Right now I'm testing on my local but eventually it will execute as an SQL agent job

Comment: Ok. I guess your user account doesn't have access to the database. you need to set that up as well as for the sql server agent account(when you start executing the ssis package via sql agent job)

Comment: True.  So can this be done within SSIS or not?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot impersonate the way you want in SSIS. It's better to set the rights on the database for those accounts who're actually executing the file

Comment: This link shows you how to do it in a script task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/start-a-net-process-as-a-different-user

Answer (score 0):

I don't take credit for this but I took this from another stackoverflow answer.

Here's the script task way to execute a process as someone else:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "filename"; //use the fullpath
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "args...";
proc.StartInfo.Domain = "domainname";
proc.StartInfo.UserName = "username";
string password = "user entered password";
for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
{
    ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
}
password = "";
proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
proc.Start();
```