# Starting application as particular user only works when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, webforms, .net-4.8

I need to open another application (e.g. notepad) as a particular user using C# web app. I noticed when I debug in Visual Studio, notepad will be opened by my own user name but in the published web app, the user name for the opened notepad is DefaultAppPool.

Following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624113/start-a-net-process-as-a-different-user), I wrote the following C# code. Notepad will start successfully when debugging in Visual Studio but it will not start in the published web application.

There will be an error if I purposely put wrong domain/username/password but when the credentials are all correct, no error is catched but notepad does not open.

Any guide or clue on what I should do?

```
try
{
    string path = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\";
    string app = @"notepad.exe";
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(app);

    SecureString password = new SecureString();
    password.AppendChar('a');
    password.AppendChar('b');
    password.AppendChar('c');
    password.AppendChar('d');

    Process p = new Process();  
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = path + app;
    p.StartInfo.Domain = "mydomain";
    p.StartInfo.UserName = "myusername";
    p.StartInfo.Password = password;
    p.Start();
    
    LabelStatus.Text = "Success";   
}
catch
{
    LabelStatus.Text = "Fail";              
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening Notepad on a web server?

Comment: This is an example for the purpose of simplifying my post and hiding my server/application name, which is a self-developed windows console app.

Comment: OK, why are you trying to open ANY program from a web server?  Are you expecting a user to visit your web site, and then open a program on their local PC, or open a program on the web server?  You can set the IIS user to be something other than DefaultAppPool, but it will still run on the web server.   I just don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm making a web site that takes data from other server using Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE). It requires a DDE client (the self-developed console app) to be opened in the web server. Users will only open the website from the web server itself in an office intranet using the URL http://localhost/website/Main.aspx. So the web site users, the program to be opened and the web servers are all in the same machine. Starting the program isn't a problem but the DDE client cannot pull any data if opened by DefaultAppPool.

Comment: It's good to know I can set the IIS user to be something other than DefaultAppPool. I will do that if I am unable to make my code works.