# How to securely erase sensitive information from memory

Tags: c#, xamarin, memory-management, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection

Security penetration tools are able to get sensitive information from Memory dump.
As far as I know setting null to any variable should be fine I guess ... But I am unable to call dispose any C# varialbes.

Basically I am planing to store everything in keychain and whenever I get the value and after using I willl be setting null to clear off...but why dispose couldn't be called ... I don't know

If there are any better way to handle sensitive data variables in xamarin kindly let me know.

Comment: All bets are off when the attacker has access to your system. Is this really where you should be focusing?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Its better to make this as tough as possible from the available methods

Comment: There is the `SecureString` class but the API's you are using with it needs to accept that type as an argument for it to be safe to use. The only other solution  is call out to use native code that can securely erase it's data once you are done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dispose()` is meant to be called on those objects that implement a destructor or finalizer.  To hide sensitive data that is lingering, I'm assuming you mean `string` values.  You could implement `SecureString`.  This will convert the area of memory where your `string` is stored into cipher text.

Proper usage is all over Stack Overflow for the `SecureString`.  But not sure if it is supported via Xamarin. At least while it is cipher text, it will not be exposed via a memory dump.  I warn you, it is a weird api to implement.

Comment: The following should be required further reading about `SecureString`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190938/is-securestring-ever-practical-in-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: @NotMe Yeah, I think that is the number one article that loads for `SecureString` in search.  But that is one of the many great articles on it.

Comment: I couldn't install SecureString in my PCL ...  it says couldn't be installed any idea please ?

Comment: @Shiva Just use [Xamarin Form's DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to access the native code. Using that, you setup an `interface` in your PCL project and implement the `interface` in your native projects.

Comment: @hvaughan3 - I am not using xamarin forms ...  :(

Comment: @Shiva I believe the idea is the same, you will just need to do it without using `DependencyService`. So you can have a `static` ISecureString property: `public static ISecureString SecureStringInstance { get; set; }`, for example, in your PCL code. Then in your Android or iOS project, when the app starts up, you assign your platform specific interface implementation to that `static` property like: `PclProj.SecureStringInstance = new SecureStringImplementation();`. Now your PCL code can us `PclProj.SecureStringInstance` assuming that it will have native code access.

Comment: @hvaughan3 - Thanks , I will give a try

Comment: @Shiva Would be interested to see your implementation if you get it working. Maybe you could post it as a second answer or an edit to your question.

Comment: @hvaughan3 - yes ,sure will do