# object oriented programming for security

Tags: java, oop

In OOP, we can assign private, protected and public to variables and methods. I know this has many advantages, but is security one of them? So that unauthorized person must not have access.

Comment: No. [None](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196207/2970947).

Comment: The design principles of Object Oriented programming have different goals than security principles that are largely based on Roles based Access Control (RBAC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "not really". The data is still in the memory, and if you dig around with reflection you can get the content of the fields. Marking fields and methods private is a way to communicate to other programmers: "Hey, this is the internal working of the class, it is prone to change and please don't touch it."

You can get the value of a private field with this:

```
// suppose we have a class
Person person = new Person("John");
// Field is from java.lang.reflect.Field
Field nameField = Person.class.getDeclaredField("name");
// tell Java to ignore the private modifier
nameField.setAccessible(true);
// now you can "steal" the private field
System.out.println(nameField.get(person));
```

Unless absolutely necessary, please do not use this is your code, and proceed with extreme caution if you ever use reflection.

Furthermore, even if the field is not accessible by language design, if we are talking security as in an external program scanning the memory, marking fields as private does not hide the data from it. After all.. the data has to *be* somewhere, right?

Comment: Thanks, for the short and precise answer.

Comment: I was thinking that it would be used, for example, in a bank database. where the account balances are set private so that you are not able to access them from outside.

Comment: For this sort of security, the public/private pattern does nothing to help. If you want a system to be secure, you have to make sure no malicious software runs on the machine, and firewall up, yadayada.

Comment: @Babydesta If you are writing a web server in Java and want to avoid leaking the plaintext password that the clients are logging in with, other than salting the database, you might also want to look into something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52861568/8557739). Just something that might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the principle of encapsulation in oops, which is information hiding. You can use access modifiers to define the visibility of classes, methods and attributes.

You implement this information-hiding mechanism by making your class attributes inaccessible from the outside and by providing getter and/or setter methods for attributes that shall be readable or updatable by other classes.

Comment: I get that, and you said hiding. why are we hiding information then?