# Password getting stored in java process memory

Tags: java, string, rest, password-protection, string-pool

I was working an issue where password is getting stored in java process memory since the password is stored in a String (hence getting stored in string pool). I made code changes to use char[]. Now the issue is, my application is consuming another service via POST CALL and while setting:

conn.setRequestProperty(key, headers.get(key));

I must convert the char[] to string and thereby creating an entry in string pool. So is there a way to handle this issue, i.e., no matter what the password should not get stored in process memory or in the worst case, any ways to minimize its living duration in the string pool.

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242150/java-equivalent-of-securestring

Comment: this thing can spark pretty much a fiery discussion, such as explained [How can I ensure the destruction of a String object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241096/4648586). though Harish suggested to use `GuardedString`, you might still end up having string somewhere, like on that `headers` dictionary instance.

Comment: Why don't you try encrypting and decrypting passwords when using char[]?

Comment: Only constants and interned Strings go to the String pool, not all Strings. Using `char[]` just allows you to erase the contents (which String doesn't allow, since it's immutable).

Comment: Sorry for off topic, but don't you think that password in http header is unsecure? So what's the sense to guard unsecure password?