# Java GuardedString - Is the random key used for encryption is stored inside Java Heap memory? If not, then where the key is persisted?

Tags: java, encryption, jvm, heap-memory, securestring

Oracle's org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString

The raw data to be converted to GuardedString needs an encryption key that is randomly generated by EncryptorImpl.class.

I wondering where the randomly generated key is persisted(to be used for decryption)?
If it is stored in Heap then it is vulnerable to attackers as they can get the key from the heap dump.

Comment: [Read the 4th paragraph of the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E28160_01/org/identityconnectors/common/security/GuardedString.html).

Comment: Duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128503/does-oracles-guardedstring-protect-sensitive-data-against-heap-or-memory-dumps  (The answer seems to be: No, it does not really protect against motivated heap dump attackers)