# Why do @Html.EditorFor and @Html.PasswordFor create different style boxes in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, editorformodel

I am currently using the `@Html.EditorFor` HTML helper for the password field. I want to use the `@Html.PasswordFor` HTML helper instead.

I copied the current code and replaced `@Html.EditorFor` with `@Html.PasswordFor`.

#### CSHTML

This is the code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control k-textbox large", placeholder = "password", @id = "password", @autocomplete = "off" } })

@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Pwd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control k-textbox large", placeholder = "password", @id = "password", @autocomplete = "off" } })
```

#### Rendered Output

The parameters are 100% the same, but these produce different style textboxes:

[image]

Note that `@Html.EditorFor` has validation and a placeholder as well, but `@Html.PasswordFor` doesn't; the later also has a different style. The validation `spam` element is also not a part of the textbox.

#### Generated HTML

Here is generated HTML code for `@Html.EditorFor`:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control k-textbox large text-box single-line password k-invalid" data-val="true" data-val-required=" " id="password" name="Password" placeholder="password" type="password" value="" aria-invalid="true">
```

Here is generated HTML code for `@Html.PasswordFor`:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required=" " htmlattributes="{ class = form-control k-textbox large, placeholder = password, id = password, autocomplete = off }" id="Pwd" name="Pwd" type="password" aria-invalid="true" class="k-invalid">
```

#### Model Definition

This is how I define those two fields in the model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Pwd { get; set; }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you *why* the decision was made to treat these differently, but while the second parameter for these particular overloads of `EditorFor()` and `PasswordFor()` both accept an anonymous object, those objects actually represent different concepts.

#### Documentation

For [`EditorFor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-editorextensions-editorfor-2(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-1))))-system-object)), the second parameter is titled `additionalViewData`:

> An anonymous object that can contain additional view data that will be merged into the [`ViewDataDictionary<TModel>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary-1?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instance that is created for the template.

For [`PasswordFor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.passwordfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-inputextensions-passwordfor-2(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-1))))-system-object)), the second parameter is titled `htmlAttributes`:

> An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.

#### Explanation

In other words, you're operating at different levels here. When you set a property called `htmlAttributes` on your anonymous object for `EditorFor()` (i.e., `additionalViewData`), that's being parsed out as HTML attributes on your rendered element:

```html
<input autocomplete="off" class="…" id="password" placeholder="password" … >
```

But when you set `htmlAttributes` on your anonymous object for `PasswordFor()` (i.e., `htmlAttributes`), that's being seen as an HTML attribute itself, as you can see in your HTML output:

```html
<input htmlattributes="{ class = …, placeholder = password, id = password, autocomplete = off }" … >
```

#### Resolution

As a result, what you *should* be doing in elevating the `htmlAttributes` one level for your `PasswordFor()` call:

```cs
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Pwd, new { @class = "form-control k-textbox large", placeholder = "password", @id = "password", @autocomplete = "off" })
```

Which *should* render something like:

```html
<input class="form-control k-textbox large" placeholder="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" … >
```

And with the CSS classes correctly set, you should also find that the presentation aligned.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the problem with the textbox style. However, the validation sign, is still displayed outside of the box ;(

Comment: I got it. I had to change the style of the Password class

Comment: @gene: What style did you alter for the `Password` class? If you let me know, I'll update my answer so it is complete. (I'll obviously credit you for discovering that.)

Comment: span#Password_validationMessage

Comment: may be you know the answer to the following question I posted the other day regarding that Password property? This is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72759111/how-to-mitigate-cwe-316-cleartext-storage-of-sensitive-information-in-memory-in?noredirect=1#comment128516152_72759111

Comment: @gene: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that question. As an aside, please be sure to mark my answer (or @Jasen's) as accepted if one of them helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The method signatures are slightly different.

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString PasswordFor<TModel,TProperty> (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
     System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> expression,
     object htmlAttributes);

public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel,TValue> (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>> expression,
    object additionalViewData);
```

You don't need to wrap the `PasswordFor` attribute object in another object. What you have is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, additionalViewData: new { htmlAttributes = new { ... } })
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Pwd, htmlAttributes: new { htmlAttributes = new { ... } })
```

It is simply:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Pwd, new { @class = "..." })
```