# Securely obtaining a logon token from user-entered credentials with LogonUser, CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials and CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, access-violation

I am trying to update an existing piece of library code that prompts an end-user for a username and password (using the normal Windows UI), and then passes these credentials to LogonUser to obtain the impersonation token for network resources.

The existing code uses `CredUIPromptForCredentials` and works as expected, but the UI is the old-style WinXP dialog.  This method has been superseded by a bunch of hoop-jumping, using [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to show the dialog, then [`CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to decode the credential blob into username, domain and password strings.

The canonical examples for P/Invoking `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer`, [from around the web](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/credui/CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer), marshal the `LPTSTR` fields using `StringBuilder`.  This is fine for username and domain, but there is no guarantee that the password won't be paged, moved or otherwise meddled with, unless the `StringBuilder` pins the memory (which I can't force it to do), and I can't programatically force the zeroing of each character when I'm done.

In the old-style code, we declare `LogonUser` and `CredUIPromptForCredentials` with an `IntPtr` password parameter.  We create the `char[]` manually, wrap it in a `GCHandle` (with `GCHandleType.Pinned`) and pass the `gch.AddrOfPinnedObject()` to `CredUIPromptForCredentials`; then pass the same `gch.AddrOfPinnedObject()` to `LogonUser`.  Finally, we call `Array.Clear` on the pinned `char[]` and dispose the `GCHandle`.

However, in the new-style code, the password parameter to `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer` is an out-only parameter, so any buffer I create is ignored.  I have declared the password parameter to be an `out IntPtr` and intend to pass this `IntPtr` to `LogonUser` (in the same manner as the old-style).  Once this has returned I intend to pass the `IntPtr` to [`SecureZeroMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to clear it out.  I am trusting (rightly or wrongly, but what option do I have?) that `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer` will pin the memory accordingly.

When I run the code, the `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` call displays the dialog correctly, and the `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer` runs.  If I put a breakpoint/watch here, I can see that the username and domain have been parsed correctly into the `StringBuilder` parameters (although the username length is hugely off), the password `IntPtr` is set to a valid value and the password length parameter is correct.

However, when I pass that to the `LogonUser` procedure, the call fails with an AccessViolationException: *Attempted to read or write protected memory.  This is often an indication that the other memory is corrupt.*

**Why does this happen?**

**Is it because I am trying to read past the end of the buffer, or because the buffer is encrypted (e.g. by DPAPI)?**

Note that the username/password is confirmed correct.  If I rip all the `IntPtr` stuff out and replace it with `StringBuilder` it does work properly.  However, this potentially allows my program to leak the password, which is against all the [recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [I](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms717803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [have](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/27/143254.aspx) [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141203/when-would-i-need-a-securestring-in-net) and try to work towards.

**What does the built-in marshalling of StringBuilder do, that I might do as well?**

*Some sample code (cropped some subsidary methods/enums for brevity, but the `DllImport`/`extern` definitions, and subsequent usages are the same):*

```
private class Native 
{ 
   [DllImport("credui", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern CredUIReturnCodes CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(
        ref CredUIInfo credUIInfo,
        int errorCode, 
        ref uint authPackage,
        IntPtr sourceAuthBuffer,
        uint sourceAuthBufferSize,
        out IntPtr targetAuthBuffer,
        out uint targetAuthBufferSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] ref bool save,
        CredWinUIFlags flags
    );

    [DllImport("credui", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(
        CredPackFlags flags,
        IntPtr authBuffer,
        uint authBufferSize,
        StringBuilder username,
        out int usernameLength,
        StringBuilder domain,
        out int domainLength,
        out IntPtr password,
        out int passwordLength
    );

    [DllImport("credui", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(
        CredPackFlags flags,
        IntPtr authBuffer,
        uint authBufferSize,
        StringBuilder username,
        out int usernameLength,
        StringBuilder domain,
        out int domainLength,
        StringBuilder password,
        out int passwordLength
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(
        string username, 
        string domain, 
        IntPtr password, 
        LogonType logonType,
        LogonProvider logonProvider, 
        out IntPtr handle
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
}

public void Test()
{
    var info = GetCredUIInfo();
    uint authPackage = 0;
    bool saveChecked = false;
    IntPtr buffer;
    uint bufferLength;

    var ui = Native.CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(
                 ref info,
                 0,
                 ref authPackage,
                 IntPtr.Zero,
                 0,
                 out buffer,
                 out bufferLength,
                 CredWinUIFlags.GenericCredentials
             );

    if (uiResult == CredUIReturnCodes.NoError)
    {
        int usernameLength = 513, 
            domainLength = 337,
            passwordLength = 256;
        StringBuilder username = new StringBuilder(usernameLength);
        StringBuilder domain = new StringBuilder(domainLength);
        IntPtr password;

        if (Native.CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(
                CredPackFlags.PackProtectedCredentials,
                buffer, bufferLength,
                username, ref usernameLength,
                domain, ref domainLength,
                password, ref passwordLength
            ))
        {
            IntPtr logonToken;
            if (Native.LogonUser(
                   username,
                   domain,
                   password,
                   LogonType.NewCredentials,
                   LogonProvider.WindowsNT50,
                   out logonToken
               ))  /*** fails here with AccessViolationException ***/
            {
                using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(logonToken))
                {
                    TestNetworkAccess();
                }
                CloseHandle(logonToken);
            }

            // TODO: Native.SecureZeroMemory(password, passwordLength);
            //       - possibly Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(password)
        }

        // TODO: Native.SecureZeroMemory(buffer, bufferLength);
        //       - possibly Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(buffer)
    }
}
```