# In Xamarin.IOS, what is the correct way to deal with passwords in memory?

Tags: ios, security, xamarin.ios, passwords, keychain

I need to safely manage passwords stored in memory on Xamarin.IOS.

What is the best way to leverage C# to securely erase the sensitive data?

[This Sec.SE link](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/74281/396) references the details on why we need to pay special attention to this risk

Comment: Use keychain for secure data. Perhaps this example is illustrative: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/Keychain/. For broader discussion of security in apps, see WWDC 2015 video [Security and Your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/706/).

Comment: You could also use SecureString, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141203/when-would-i-need-a-securestring-in-net