# Using SecureString the secure way

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, securestring

How to get back the value from SecureString the most secure way?

I was found this code to get the value back.

```
public static String SecureStringToString(SecureString value)
{
     IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
     try
     {
         valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(value);
         return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);
     }
     finally
     {
         Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
     }
}
```

Is it secure to use this way or it's destroy the whole security of SecureString?

Comment: IMO, `SecureString` is mostly silly and security through obscurity.  As you note, the fact you can decrypt it means it's mostly not secure in any meaningful sense.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141203/when-would-i-need-a-securestring-in-net) goes into some more detail.

Comment: If you /ever/ have the value in a regular string it has lost almost all of its value.  Pretty much, don’t use SecureString. It’s an expensive non-solution.